# Grab 33 new photos on load more using Instagram API

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, instagram-api

I have a collection view that loads 33 recent media posts using Instagram API. What I am looking to achieve is once scrolling to bottom of collection view to load the next 33 media posts. The functionality of scrolling down to load more is already in place I just can't seem to figure out how to tell Instagram load the next 33 posts. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would make sense to be able to set a starting point parameter of sorts in the request so that it tells IG to grab 'y' new posts from starting point 'x' (or something like that)...

Answer (score 0):

Since each media that you retrieve will have an ID, You can use pagination to get the next set of data as stated on Instagram API documentation

```
{
    ...
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",
        "next_max_id": "13872296"
    }
}
```

source: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/